# SELECT statement for 3 employee Id's

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Please can someone help me with the SQL code that list all the data for the 3 Employee ID's:
60-578-2269, 50-218-3739 and 80-772-4580 ? I was only able to pull the data for one Employee ID below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   [dbo].Employee_Certification 
WHERE  Employee_ID = '60-578-2269'
```

Also, the sql statement that list every employee that was hired after 1st April 2021, in date format 04/01/2021. I ran this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   [dbo].Employee_Certification 
WHERE  Date_Hired> = 01/04/2021
```

but the error message below came up:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 23 Conversion failed when converting
> the nvarchar value '4/1/21' to data type int.

Answer (score 4):

For the first query use `WHERE IN (...)` with a tuple of employee IDs which you want to find:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].Employee_Certification
WHERE Employee_ID IN ('60-578-2269', '50-218-3739', '80-772-4580');
```

For the second query, use a proper date literal which SQL Server will recognize:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].Employee_Certification
WHERE Date_Hired >= '20210401';
```